# Send keystroke to caret

Tags: vba

I have an onscreen number pad 0-9, I'm trying to send a keystroke to a checkbox when a user clicks the button of that number (essentially a touchscreen keyboard). There are several textbox's and I want to send it to the one that currently has the caret in it. I've tried `SendKeys.Send("1")` but that doesn't send it. What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are encountering is because when the user clicks on any of your buttons, the button takes focus and the textbox loses focus, and therefore any keystrokes are sent to the control with focus, i.e. the button.

One possible way around this might be to use a global variable to store a reference to the last textbox to have lost focus on the form (via the `On Exit` or `On Lost Focus` events of each textbox), and then populate the content of this stored textbox with an appropriate value as part of the `On Click` event of each button.

A very simple example of this might be something along the lines of:

```
Dim LastTextBox As TextBox

Private Sub TextBox1_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
    Set LastTextBox = TextBox1
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
    Set LastTextBox = TextBox2
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click()
    If Not LastTextBox Is Nothing Then LastTextBox = "1"
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click()
    If Not LastTextBox Is Nothing Then LastTextBox = "2"
End Sub
```